# How to alter the value of a div on each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to create a puzzle.I have 12 div.Each div contains different value up to 12.I have button like start now.I want to change my div value on each click of the start now button.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W55xc/)

```
<div id="container">
        <div class="finder">
            <div class="block1">    <div id="one"><h1>1</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="two"><h1>2</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="three"><h1>3</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="four"><h1>4</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="five"><h1>5</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="six"><h1>6</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="seven"><h1>7</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="eight"><h1>8</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="nine"><h1>9</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="ten"><h1>10</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="eleven"><h1>11</h1></div>
            </div>
            <div class="block1">    <div id="twelve"><h1>12</h1></div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="button">
            <div id="startButton">
                <button>Start</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

js is

```
 $(".finder").css('display','none');
      $("#startButton").click(function () {
        $(".finder").css('display','block');
      });
      var myDiv;
      $(".block1 div").on('click', function(){myDiv = $(this)});
      $(".block1 div").click(function () {
        if(myDiv.text() < 12)
        {
            myDiv.text(parseInt(myDiv.text())+1);
        }
        if(myDiv.text() > 12)
        {
            myDiv.text(1);
            myDiv.text(parseInt(myDiv.text())+1);
        }
      });
```

How can i change the values?

Comment: Your code already seems to be altering the values, or am I missing something here?

Comment: yes..its altering..But its not working with startnow button

Comment: Why are you setting `myDiv` in one event handler, but using it in a different one? I don't think there's any assurance of which order they'll execute in.

Comment: What do you want to change them to when the start button is clicked?

Comment: if i press start button first the first div value must be 1.. then second time it can have 2 to 12.. any of this

Comment: I would never compare a string against an integer. You are using parseInt, why not within the if statement? .text() returns a string

Comment: Why does the counter roll over to 2 instead of 1, once the value is greater than 12?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have provided a solution below.  One of the key takeaways you should get from it, is that when an event handler is used `this` will be assigned the element the event was trigger on within the bound function.

**To Fill the boxes with random numbers use this code**

```
$(function() {
    //Array of values
    var values = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12];

    $( "input[type=submit], button" )
      .button()
      .click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
      });
      $(".finder").css('display','none');
      $("#startButton").click(function () {

          var tmpValues = values.slice(); //copy array


          $(".block1 div h1").each(function(){
               var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*tmpValues.length);
               //assign html to random array value that gets removed from array
               $(this).html(tmpValues.splice(r,1));   
          });
        $(".finder").css('display','block');
      });

      $(".block1 div").click(function () {

        //Instead of setting myDiv use $(this) which will refer to the div
        //We can grab the value of the H1 within the div using a scoped selector
        var value = parseInt($("h1",this).html());


        //Set the html of the clicked div
        //When setting the html we must include new value in h1 to maintain style
        //Ternary expression tidies up the logic, not sure why it sets to to 2 though?
        $(this).html("<h1>" + ((value > 12) ? 2: value+1) + "</h1>");
      });
  });
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/W55xc/3/

Comment: -My problem is when I click start button it will not come with different values..

Comment: @Nithu so you just want random values in the boxes?

Comment: yes..On the click of start button. User can select new game by clicking start then there will not be the same value.

Comment: @Nithu lets further clarify, I click start, i should get 1-12 in the boxes, I click start again, does it reset at that point to 1-12 or is it random?

Comment: it must be random..Like memorize game. two boxes values are same.We can identify that number

Comment: @KevinBowersox-I need a help in the above example

Answer (score 1):

I didnt quite get the question, but I guess you want to generate *random numbers* for the div's, right? Use `Math.random()`

```
$(".block1 div").each(function() {
  $(this).children('h1').text(Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1)); // Generate a random number <-> [1, 12]
}
```